# Sending out an automated email

Tags: c#, email

I have an service that needs to send out automated emails on failures. I feel like i have it set up but i keep on receiving the following error:

```
Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response 
was: 4.3.2 Service not available
```

I cant quite figure out where i went wrong, but here is my code:

```
public static void AutoEmail()
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient newClient = new SmtpClient();
        newClient.Host = "host name";
        newClient.Port = Port number;
        newClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
        "username", "password");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("something@email.com"));
        mail.Body = "This is a test message.";
        mail.Subject = "Test - " + DateTime.Now;
        mail.From = new MailAddress("something2@email.com");

        newClient.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Log.WriteException("Error in Email", ex);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: at which point are you getting the exception??

Comment: It hits the catch once it hits the line that says `newClient.Send(mail);`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not available, closing transmission channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732859/the-server-response-was-4-3-2-service-not-available-closing-transmission-chann)

Comment: Confirm where problem exists by by using [Telnet to test](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/03/15/Troubleshooting-email_2C00_-the-Telnet-way.aspx) your connection to the server.

Comment: @BradRem - I got the same error.

Comment: Then the problem most probably does not exist in your code but on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure SMTP server you are using permits applications to send emails? I had met with similar issue and root cause was Exchange server was rejecting the send request due to insufficient permissions. And I have the same steps in my code as in yours. Check for permissions.

Comment: Is there a way that i can check for that?

Comment: If you using Exchange server, then the server administrator will help you with that.

Comment: `username` that you specify in NetworkCredential should be having permissions to send emails. Also check if the port number is correct. You can comment out the port setting in the code to set it to default SMTP port.

Comment: I am using the port that i was told to use, but i am checking about permissions right now.

Comment: Permissions ended up being the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
newClient .UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Does it help ?

The SMTP server name only works on a computer within the network that contains that SMTP server.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but unfortunately it did not seem to help. Still getting the same exception at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure SMTP server's host name and port number in your program is correct. All the other code in your program seem fine. 
I experienced the same error before. At the end, I changed to the correct host name and port number and everything works. 
For example, Outlook.com Or Hotmail email accounts

```
host="smtp-mail.outlook.com" port="25" enableSsl="true"
```

https://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-com-pop-settings/