# how to solve Message=Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not available

Tags: c#, smtp

C# code behind to send mails to different users. i am getting an error   Message=Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not available

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Email,Password from Login where Email =@email", con);
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("abc@xxx.com");//Email will be sent through this Mail
                msg.To.Add(SEmail_Display.Text);//A mail will be sent to the address carried from previous page.
                msg.Subject = " Recover your Password";
                msg.Body = ("Your Username is:" + Email + "<br/><br/>" + "Your Password is:" + Password);
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient();
                smt.Host = "mail.yash.com";
                System.Net.NetworkCredential ntwd = new NetworkCredential();
                ntwd.UserName = "gd.mk"; //Credentials to access mail 
                ntwd.Password = "myPassword";  
                smt.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smt.Credentials = ntwd;

                smt.Port = 587;
                smt.EnableSsl = true;
                smt.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normally a permission issue

See accepted answer on this:

[Sending out an automated email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335882/sending-out-an-automated-email)