# C# script task to send email out at end of SSIS process returns error: '4.3.2 Service not available'

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, smtp, exchange-server

The requirement is to send an email to a company at the end of an SSIS process to raise tickets with them. I have written a C# script task and created a method that sends out an email via an SMTP client object. I need to understand what the problem is exactly so that I can discuss it with the Exchange admins.

It would be good to retrieve more information about how the server is being called and what is being sent.

I have ensured I am using port 25. I also tried sending an email through Powershell and using the SSIS email task component and receive the same error each way.

```
public partial class ScriptMain
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string htmlMessageFrom = "name.name@comp.com";
        string htmlMessageTo = "name.name@comp.com";
        string htmlMessageSubject = "Support Request";
        string htmlMessageBody = EmailBody();
        string smtpServer = "smtp.dom.local";

        SendMailMessage(htmlMessageFrom, htmlMessageTo, htmlMessageSubject, htmlMessageBody, true, smtpServer);
    }
    #region workhorse
    private static void SendMailMessage(string From, string SendTo, string Subject, string Body, bool IsBodyHtml, string Server)
    {
        MailMessage htmlMessage;
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient;

        htmlMessage = new MailMessage(From, SendTo, Subject, Body);
        htmlMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml;

        mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(Server);
        mySmtpClient.Port = 25;
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;



        //Console.WriteLine(mySmtpClient.ServicePoint.ToString());

        mySmtpClient.Send(htmlMessage);
    }

    public static string EmailBody()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=servname;Initial Catalog=databsae;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        string emailBody = "Please see the following tickets for your attention: \r\n\r\n";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT a.*, b.Title " +
            "FROM IT.table a " +
            "LEFT JOIN IT.table b ON a.field = b.field " +
            "WHERE a.EmailSent = 0;"
            , connection)
         )
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    emailBody = emailBody
                         + "Request/Problem: " + reader["field"].ToString() + "\r\n"
                         + "DevOps Id: " + reader["field"].ToString() + "\r\n"
                         + "comp Department: " + reader["field"].ToString() + "\r\n"
                         + "comp BI Developer Contact: " + reader["field"].ToString() + "\r\n"
                         + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }


        return emailBody;
    }
    #endregion
```

The execution fails at `mySmtpClient.Send(htmlMessage);` and the error returned is the following:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Service not available, closing transmission >channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not available'

Comment: The email is reaching the SMTP server but is then being explicitly rejected, consult its logs for the reason, probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732859/the-server-response-was-4-3-2-service-not-available-closing-transmission-chann

Comment: Port 25 is not a secure mail port number.  So you cannot use credentials with port 25.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard built into SSIS Send Mail Task @digitalBlade?

Comment: @Arthur I tried the SSIS Send Mail Task as stated and the same error was returned.

Comment: @AlexK. I have emailed the IT service desk that manages the Exchange service requesting to view the logs.